# How to pass inputbox's id to button id value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the input box id to buttons form attribute value when the input box is edited. i have some code but in do not worked.

```
Enter name: <input type="text" value="Mickey" id="T" oninput="myFunction(this.id);">

<button type="submit" id="b" form="bf" >submit</button>

<script>
function myFunction(id) {

  $("#b[form='bf']").val(id);
  
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: a `<button>` element doesn't have a value property, so your function won't do anything. Where exactly did you want the ID property passed in that function to eventually go to?

Comment: i want the id of inputbox to button's form attribute's  value. like inputbox id=2. I want that id to button's form=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
function myFunction(id) {
  $("#b").attr('form', id);  
}
```